# how to speed up the compilation of large c# solutions

Tags: c#, compilation, solution

I have a C# solution with about 60 large projects. After a get latest version the compilation takes a lot of time. Do you have similar problems and what should be done?

Comment: Get a faster computer. RAM and SSD's makes a huge difference. BTW what is long?  Like DotNetNuke long (30 min) or like 1-2 minutes?

Comment: i have 4GB RAM and it still takes 15 minutes after a get latest version

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answers which have helped! :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to be compiling all the projects? If there are some static projects which never get modified you can turn off compiling them by going to:

```
Build -> Configuration Manager
```

and then deselecting any large static projects which aren't changing. (Obviously remember to switch them on again when you make a change!) :)

This is especially good for skipping merge modules and installers (which take ages to compile) if you just want to run a debug of the code.

Andy.

Answer (score 2):

Pre-compile some projects first. Make them to library if possible. Then, add the projects back as reference. It will greatly shorten the compile time.